# RabbitMQ is not deleting all messages

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message

I have a current situation in which I am attempting to purge all messages within a RabbitMQ Queue. I have tried purging the queue as well as deleting the queue itself but each time I try to re-create the same queue again via the Web UI or code, it still insists that it has some messages to process despite the fact I am unable to retrieve a single message from the queue. Has anyone come across this issue before because it is quite bizarre?

Comment: Is this a heavily loaded RabbitMQ Cluster, or more like a dev environment?

Comment: It is being used in a production environment quite a lot. I also read an article today that kind of describe the current situation I am experiencing. https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/jJ0TEkxCfiY/m/fdbTws0GAwAJ?pli=1